# What is the code to know which words are different between two dfm?

Tags: r, quanteda

I have two dfm and I would like to know which words are missing/different between them.
For example,

```
library(quanteda)

df1 <- data.frame(Text = c("Stackoverflow is a great place where very skilled data scientists are willing to help you. Trust me you will need help if you are doing a PhD. So Stack is immensely useful. Thank you guys to sort this out for me."), stringsAsFactors = F)

corpus1 <- corpus(df1, text_field = "Text")

df2 <- data.frame(Text = c("Stackoverflow is a great place where very skilled data scientists are willing to help you. Trust me you will need help if you are doing a PhD."), stringsAsFactors = F)
corpus2 <- corpus(df2, text_field = "Text")

dfm1 <- dfm(corpus1, remove_punct = TRUE)

dfm2 <- dfm(corpus2, remove_punct = TRUE)
```

I would like to see which words in dfm2 are not in dfm1. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: are you using `quanteda`? if so you can extract words using `tokens` (`tokens(dfm1, remove_numbers = TRUE,  remove_punct = TRUE)`) . You can then use set functions on the vector (`?setdiff`)

Comment: @user20650 yes! thanks! this strategy works as well. I signalled the correct answer below as it is quicker to do it. Thanks

Comment: If you want to use splitting string approach, you can also do `setdiff(strsplit(df1$Text, "\\s+")[[1]], strsplit(df2$Text, "\\s+")[[1]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question was how to compare the feature sets of two (**quanteda**) dfm objects, not to reinvent a method for tokenizing the texts.

```
> setdiff(featnames(dfm1), featnames(dfm2))
 [1] "so"        "stack"     "immensely" "useful"    "thank"     "guys"     
 [7] "sort"      "this"      "out"       "for"
```

to get the features in dfm1 that are not in dfm2.

@JBGruber's answer also works but in the forthcoming v2, we deprecate the usage of `dfm_select()` where `pattern` is another dfm

Answer (score 2):

The answer above works well. However, I think it can be done cleaner using `dfm_select`:

```
dfm_select(dfm1, pattern = dfm2, selection = "remove")
#> Document-feature matrix of: 1 document, 10 features (0.0% sparse).
#> 1 x 10 sparse Matrix of class "dfm"
#>        features
#> docs    so stack immensely useful thank guys sort this out for
#>   text1  1     1         1      1     1    1    1    1   1   1
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do it:

```
corpus1 <- unlist(strsplit(df1$Text, "\\s"))
corpus2 <- unlist(strsplit(df2$Text, "\\s"))
```

Get rid of punctuation:

```
corpus1 <- gsub("[.;!?,]", "", corpus1)
corpus2 <- gsub("[.;!?,]", "", corpus2)
```

Get words in `corpus1` but not in `corpus2`:

```
corpus1[!corpus1 %in% corpus2]
 [1] "So"        "Stack"     "immensely" "useful"    "Thank"     "guys"      "sort"      "this"     
 [9] "out"       "for"
```

Comment: Perfect. For future reference: his code can be applied directly to the dfm results and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Please note the edit on how to get rid of punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

Base R one-liner:

```
unlist(strsplit(df1$Text, "\\s+"))[!(unlist(strsplit(gsub("[[:punct:]]",
                                                          "",
                                                          tolower(df1$Text)),
                           "\\s+")) %in%
        (unlist(strsplit(gsub("[[:punct:]]", "", tolower(df2$Text)),
                         "\\s+"))))]
```

Data used:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Text = c("Stackoverflow is a great place where very skilled data scientists are willing to help you. Trust me you will need help if you are doing a PhD. So Stack is immensely useful. Thank you guys to sort this out for me."), stringsAsFactors = F)

df2 <- data.frame(Text = c("Stackoverflow is a great place where very skilled data scientists are willing to help you. Trust me you will need help if you are doing a PhD."), stringsAsFactors = F)
```